# Remote windows updates to domain machines from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winrm, windows-update

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that can be used by domain users with admin privileges to check for windows updates, list the update, prompt user to continue and then install the updates with restart. I am having success with all of the steps until the last section when I get an error. I know that Windows updates are blocked from remote sessions so I have the PowerShell script create a scheduled task with the commands and then run the task.
Here are my commands

```
$computer = read-host "Enter computer name"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -ScriptBlock   {
   Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
   Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
    Import-Module PsWindowsUpdate
    Enable-PSRemoting
    Get-WUList
}

Write-Warning "This action will cause the machine to update and restart" -WarningAction Inquire
Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll –IgnoreReboot
invoke-WUJob -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -Script { Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -SendReport } -Confirm:$false -verbose -RunNow
```

When I run the command, it prompts for the machine name, lists the updates available and then asks to continue, when I click yes I get the following errors and verbose statements. Checking the Get-WUHistory on the test target shows the attempt to update but shows failed.

```
invoke-WUJob : [xxx] Connecting to remote server xxx failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.  
Default credentials with Negotiate over HTTP can be used only if the target machine is part of the TrustedHosts list or the Allow implicit 
credentials for Negotiate option is specified. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\me\Documents\Untitled2.ps1:13 char:1
+ invoke-WUJob -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -Script { Inst ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (CDC2:String) [Invoke-WUJob], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExplicitCredentialsRequired,PSSessionStateBroken
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "(4/21/2023 3:45:37 PM) Invoke WU job: powershell.exe -Command " Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -SendReport -Ign
oreReboot "" on target "xxx".
VERBOSE: Try to connect xxx. Test 1
VERBOSE: Try to connect xxx. Test 2
VERBOSE: Try to connect xxx. Test 3
VERBOSE: Registering task: PSWindowsUpdate
VERBOSE: Starting task: PSWindowsUpdate
```

I checked WinRM on both my local machine and the test target. It is running and listening for commands.